# Поставить третью систему

Tags: linux, windows, grub

Есть Windows 7 и Linix. Хочу дополнительно к ним поставить Windows 10.

Вопрос, надо ли что-то делать с grub'ом переду установкой Win10? Или можно по стандартной схеме просто поставить Win10, затем загрузиться с LiveUSB, откуда установить и настройть grub? Или же следует сначала откатиться от grub'а до виндового загрузчика, чтобы Win10 при установке смог его определить?

Повторю, что в итоге я хочу получить Win7 + Linux + Win10.

Comment: По своему опыту могу сказать, что Windows всегда отказывался определять другие системы. Обычно порядок установки таков: Windows в порядке возрастания версий, Linux. Иначе, что-то мне подсказывает, что придётся загружаться с LiveCD и восстанавливать GRUB.

Comment: Раньше установщики виндов ломали загрузочную область вроде? Поэтому grub вообще отвалится, его придется заново настраивать.

Comment: @LEQADA, меня не волнует восстановление груба. Меня волнует доступность семёрки после этого.

Comment: @Bars, см. комментарий выше.

Comment: @Qwertiy, если вы не тронете раздел с Windows 7, то в конечном счёте доступ к нему восстановит груб. Вам в любом случае придётся его восстанавливать, что загружать Linux.

Comment: @LEQADA, я не трону раздел, но физический жёсткий диск для семёрки и десятки один и тот же.

Comment: @Qwertiy, это не имеет значения в этом деле. Смело ставьте десятку. При загрузке увидите "Choose an operating system" с вариантом выбора Windows 7.

Comment: @LEQADA, а откуда такой вариант? Она же груб увидит сейчас, а не семёрку?

Comment: @Qwertiy, точно сказать не могу, но мне кажется, что Windows свои разделы видит из установщика. Но если нет, то grub в итоге всё восстановит.

Comment: @LEQADA, получается, груб в любом случае найдёт все 3 системы, независимо от того, найдёт десятка семёрку при установке или нет. Если всё верно, опубликуй это в виде ответа - именно об этом я спрашивал.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

После того, как вы установите Windows 10 (не повреждая файлы других ОС) нужно будет загрузиться с Linux и выполнить `boot-repair` в терминале. Не зависимо от того, увидит десятка семёрку или нет (хотя по идее должна увидеть), GRUB восстановит доступ ко всем трём ОС.

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю что надо поставить 10, а потом с флешки запилить grub и настроить его. Мне кажется так будет лучше.

Comment: Я не это спросил.

Comment: 7 будет доступна, если сделаете как я вам написал. Главное для 10 диск сделать. Ни чего не должно затереться.

Comment: Т. е. не важно, что инсталлятор десятки не увидит семёрку?

Comment: А зачем ему на нее смотреть. Если бы он видел ее,то он бы ее предложил ее обновить, а это грозить потерей 7. Вам надо просто 10 установить на другой диск, а дальше уже разбираться с загрузчиком grub, чтоб он давал выбор между 3 системами

Comment: Могу ошибаться, но вроде десятка более старые версии windows помещает себе в подменю. Поэтому и возник вопрос, надо ли что-то делать, чтобы она увидела, что семёрка существует. Груб-то она по-любому сотрёт.

Comment: Для этого советую поставить на отдельный диск и не ставить стандартный Windows загрузчик

Comment: Эм.. Поставить Windows без загрузчика? А это вообще возможно разве?

Comment: Когда установите 10 она хоть как поставит свой загрузчик